# variable assigned to zero gives error during the validation,

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array which has many arrays.

school_subject = [ [5,0],[5,-5],[3,4,0],[4,,0,7] ];

I am looping the array to check the variables if it has any negative values or non number etc... zero is accepted value and number should be between zero to 20.

The code works well. But zero is also gives error. Could anyone please suggest me. Thanks.

```
     for(let i=0; i < school_subject.length; i++){          
        for(let j=0; j < school_subject[i].row.length; j++){
            curVal = school_subject[i].row[j].val;  
            console.log('i'+i+'j'+j+'cur'+curVal);

            if (curVal == "") { console.log('empty'+curVal); }
            else if (curVal != "" & curVal >=0 & curVal <=20) {
                console.log('good'+curVal+"save to db"); }
        }           
    }
```

I would like zero is also accepted value.

Comment: `elseif`? That's a syntax error.

Comment: your if condition doesn't contain `{` braces

Comment: Also, the first `if` is missing parenthesis. I wonder how _The code works well. But zero is also gives error._ is possible, since the code has many syntax errors already.

Comment: @melpomene You're right, with `elision=true`. Linters (and compilers) won't like that, though it's irrelevant for the question.

Comment: Sorry about the errors. I edited my code now. problem is zero value is valid and i am checking only null in the validation. But how the zero value gives the error as if the variable is null!

Answer (score 0):

There are errors in the code you've provided idk how you even managed to compile this. But if you want to filter empty elements from your array don't compare them like x == "", it will return true if x = 0.

You need to compare them with null to filter.
x == null

Comment: still shows error for zero! when i check it in the console it shows zero only

Comment: change your curVal == "" and curVal != "" to curVal == null and curVal != null

Comment: I changed to curVal == null and curVal != null 
now no error message for zero and also no error message for null. 
I would like to display error message for null.